# NTFS Partition Will Not Mount or Get Fixed

Tags: 18.04, mount, ntfs

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and I'm getting strange results when trying to mount a 1TB external volume to a fresh install. It works 100% fine in Windows, and chkdsk doesn't report any errors. 
Despite that, when I try to mount it through the Disks app, the play button does literally nothing and trying to repair the file system gives me this:
[image: File System Repair Error]

If you're curious, this is what the page says:
[image: The Partition Information of my Drive]

It's worth noting that my Windows partition on my boot drive mounts without a single error.

I can't remember for certain, but I believe trying ntfsfix crashed my system.
I believe I turned off hibernation and I know I turned off fast startup. Every time I turn off my system, I do it through the shutdown/restart function inside the operating systems.

EDIT: I tried to run ntfsfix and got this result:
Mounting volume... Error opening '/dev/sda1': Permission denied
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Error opening '/dev/sda1': Permission denied
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Permission denied
Error opening '/dev/sda1': Permission denied

Comment: Are you sure it is a NTFS formatted partition? Windows also provides newer filesystem called ReFS (Resilient File System). It uses the same partition type id (07) as NTFS, so Ubuntu might see it as NTFS.

Comment: The errors shown in your first screenshot may not be related to the problem but may be falsely reported, possibly as a result of the problem, whatever that may be.